# Get data from previous option in a select as well as data from current option

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

So I know scoping in JavaScript can be a little wonky and I've tried a few different things including attaching the variable declaration to the window (i.e. window.var) and declaring the variable inside and outside different parts of the function but to no avail. Here's what I've got:

```
$(".some_field").on('focus', function () {

    // Store the previous option value before the change
    prev = String($(":selected", $(this)).data('option_id'));

}).change( function() {

    alert(prev); // alerts '4'

    current = String($(":selected", $(this)).data('option_id'));
    alert(current) // alerts '5'

    alert(prev); // alerts '5' ..... it should alert '4'
});
```

Essentially within the change function I need to do stuff with both the previous and current option id's

Comment: prev_option_id and option_id are same as you're assigning the same for both...

Comment: Yes you're right... I'm starting to realize that it isn't a scope issue... However I'm still not sure how to get the desired functionality

Comment: `String($(this).data('option_id'))` ???

Comment: Unfortunately that shows as 'undefined'

Comment: You only have a single `prev` variable for all the `.some_field` elements?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure what you're asking me here. Every time the .some_field are select elements with options, the options store the data element data-option_id='a number' every time I change that particular select field I want to save the option_id of the option I'm changing from and then once the select field has changed save the option_id of what I changed to and then I'm going to do some stuff involving both those ids. Right now though, I can't get the previous id to remain constant...

Comment: I mean that when you focus one element, select an option, and then focus the next, the `focus` on the second element might be triggered before the `change` on the first.

Comment: Hmm... I think you might be right there @Bergi can you suggest a way to get around that?

Comment: Don't store it as a global variable, but as a second data attribute (next to `option_id`) maybe?

Comment: So @Bergi I did some troubleshooting and you are definitely correct as to the problem, however your suggested solution will not work well if I'm changing the <select> multiple times. Unless I'm thinking of this wrong in which case would you care to post a more formal answer outside the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a global, I recommend decorating the input with an old value data attribute.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/zpe7azsq/16/

For example:

```
$(".some_field").on('focus', function () {
    $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).data('option_id'));
}).change(function () {
    alert("Old value on focus was: " + $(this).data('oldValue'));
    alert("Current option_id value: "+$(this).data('option_id'));
});
```

Comment: Not quite... I need both the option_id it changed to AND the option_id it changed from. That is why the on('focus') clause is in there to begin with.

Comment: Oh I see.  I updated my answer to store the previous value in another data attribute.  This avoids global variables as well.

Comment: We're getting close here... Problem is in your first alert it spits out undefined as the $(this) in that line is referencing the newly selected option where as the 'oldValue' data is stored in the previous option which we have now lost... Your fiddle is using an input element, remember we're talking about select elements here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one variable/property for storing the previous value *per element*. A global variable won't help. Actually you don't even need those `focus` events.

```
$(".some_field").each(function () {
     $(this).data('id_value', $(":selected", this).data('option_id'));
}).change(function(e) {
     var previous = $(this).data('id_value'),
         current = $(":selected", this).data('option_id');

     alert(…); // or whatever

     $(this).data('id_value', current);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With @Scott 's answer as a guide here is what ended up working for me. I used the parent element to store the data instead... @Bergi's answer also works though!

```
$(".some_field").on('focus', function () {
    // Store the previous option value before the change
    $(this).parent().data('prev_option_id', $(":selected", $(this)).data('option_id'));
}).change( function() {
    current = String($(":selected", $(this)).data('option_id'));
    alert("Old value on focus was: " + $(this).parent().data('prev_option_id'));
    alert("Current option_id value: "+current);
});
```